# How to deactivate pdf preview in files

Tags: files

I have a large folder of pdfs. Every time I open it with files it has to load these little preview icons which takes pretty much time. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pantheon-files uses a thumbnailer daemon called [tumbler](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler) . You can disable generation of thumbnails for PDFs by opening a terminal and editing the config file.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc
```

Search for the section listed below-

```
# PDF/PS thumbnailer
[PopplerThumbnailer]
Disabled=false
Priority=1
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0
```

Change `Disabled=false` to `Disabled=true` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano)

Then reset your thumbnail cache  with `rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails`

Note: Rather than disabling thumbnails for all PDFs, you could set the `Locations` or `MaxFileSize` options to your liking. Unfortunately though, as far as I can tell the `Locations` setting only allows you to whitelist rather than blacklist folders.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Now it opens the folder much quicker!

Comment: rm -r ~/.thumbnails
it does not work in loki

Answer (score 0):

Files also uses **evince-thumbnailer**. Need to disable both `[PopplerThumbnailer]` and `[DesktopThumbnailer]` from `/etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc` for disable pdf's. But it's disables more than just  pdf's. To be specific, all thumbnailers under `/usr/share/thumbnailers/` directory.

```
[DesktopThumbnailer]
Disabled=true
Priority=1
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0
```

Or maybe you can try:

Erase `application/pdf` from `/usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer` **MimeType** key.